# ComponentDidMount( ) function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend, dispatch

componentDidMount() is called just once but the dispatch and subscribe function inside it are called more than once...
1st line of this function executes for the first time only, but the subscribe function is called every time my component is re-rendered. How does react reaches subscribe function without encountering console.log("mounted"), i.e., the first line of function?

```
componentDidMount() {
     console.log("mounted"); //executed just once
      const {store}=this.props; 
      store.subscribe(()=>{
        console.log("SUBSCRIBE"); // executed everytime my funct is re rendered
        this.forceUpdate();
      })
     store.dispatch(addMovies(movies));
     console.log("State is :", store.getState());
   }
```

Comment: How is this component being used?  It's possible that you're rendering separate/multiple instances of this component, and each of those is hitting the `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: console.log("SUBSCRIBE"); // executed everytime my funct is re rendered
yes. becase whenever there is a state update in store , it (callback) will be executed

Answer (score 1):

You've subscribed to your redux store and provided a callback.

[subscribe listener](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener)

> Adds a change listener. ***It will be called any time an action is
> dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have
> changed.*** You may then call `getState()` to read the current state tree
> inside the callback.

The callback will be invoked any time an action has been dispatched, and the state tree might have changed. This includes ***any*** action dispatched to the store by ***any*** other component, not just the component the subscription is created in.

Seems if there is a one-to-one relationship between component rerender and redux store updating that this component is likely dispatching an action that eventually causes it to be rerendered.